# Dependencies conflict when adding firebase ML-kit

Tags: android, dependencies, firebase-mlkit

I am getting the following conflict in dependencies in app gardle while adding the firebase ml kit. Don't know how to resolve this ?

[image: conflict in dependencies]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this just a warning message or stopping you from build success ?

Anyways excluding `com.android.support` works as it worked for me in my project.

Posting my gradle important bits and pieces from my project which uses ml-kit with targetSDK 28 and hope these changes works for you too.

Module gradle:

```
    android{

    defaultConfig {

            /.. bla bla bla ....
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
     buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                //...
            }
        }
     compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

    configurations.all {   //this piece is important to avoid duplicates
        exclude group: 'com.android.support',
                module: 'support-v4' 
    }

    }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation('com.android.support:design:28.0.0') {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' 
//  enable this if still issue exists
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0') {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    // Dependencies for working withRepoContract Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in guild.gradle (Project)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Gradle :

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

      }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    roomVersion = '1.1.1'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
}
```

Gradle dependency errors mainly depend on versions we use and internal duplicate libs used by the dependencies.
So posted things along with dependencies those worked for me.

Hope this helps for your fix.

Comment: I changed my files specially exclude in configuration.all, But the problems remain same, it is showing same error

Comment: Hi thanks! it worked, but it worked with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1' and i was using 19.0.3 latest one.

Comment: Great going. happy coding @Akash